# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twilio.Twilio

Tags: java, twilio-api

I am trying to call Twilio SMS API to trigger SMS using my java code. I am using twilio provided supporting library. All looks fine when I run the code in IDE however I am getting below error when convert into Jar and run it by passing the parameter

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/twilio/Twilio
>           at twilioSMS.TwilioSmsMsging.main(TwilioSmsMsging.java:15) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twilio.Twilio
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           ... 1 more

Below is my code

```
package twilioSMS;
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;

public class TwilioSmsMsging {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String ACCOUNT_SID = args[0];  
    String AUTH_TOKEN  = args[1]; 
    String toMobileNumber = args[2];  
    String fromMobileNumber = args[3];  
    String smsMessage = args[4];    

    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    Message message = Message.creator(new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(toMobileNumber),new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(fromMobileNumber),smsMessage).create();

    System.out.println(message.getSid());

}
```

}

Comment: have you made a "jar with dependencies"? is the lib on the classpath?

Comment: No. I have tried twilio-7.x.x.jar and not twilio-7.x.x-with-dependencies.jar.. But all the lib are in classpath

Comment: @Pali now I have tried using twilio-7.x.x-with-dependencies.jar and having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

My bad.. I have to export as runnable jar however I have exported as jar. Now issue resolved after exporting as runnable jar.

Comment: have a look at maven, the jar plugin and assembly plugin to make yourselfe independable of your IDE